# Not getting the `Self-Learner` badge

Tags: support, badges

One of my answers to my own questions got its third upvote yesterday at 19:01. But I have not got the [**Self-Learner** badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/68258#68258) badge yet. Check out the image:

[image]

This is the [link of the post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31905183/emulator-does-not-show-home-screen-after-waiting-more-than-half-of-hour/32234335#32234335) that shows three upvotes. And my newest badge is [**Primer**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/281615#281615) which I got on 23rd August 2016.

Why am I not getting the **Self-Learner** badge?

Here is [the link of my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5055401/inzimam-tariq-it) on which **Primer** badge is the newest.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You [already earned that badge on July 15](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/14/self-learner?userid=5055401) for a different question/answer pair. You can only earn the Self-Learner badge once.